# Debug Failure. File has unknown extension. How do I prevent this error in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, gulp

I'm learning how to build and app using Angular, Node, TypeScript and Gulp.

To set up environment variables, I have created a .env file.

Now, when I run my project, I get the error:

> Debug Failure. File has unknown extension.

How can I correct this error?

I have other empty file names such as .gitignore and .babelrc that don't cause any errors, but I don't see any file where these exceptions are stored.

```
[default] Checking started in a separate process...
C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.j
s:3550
            throw e;
            ^

Error: Debug Failure. File  has unknown extension.
    at Object.extensionFromPath (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_mo
dules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:3706:15)
    at C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_modules\typescript\lib\types
cript.js:69734:46
    at Array.map (native)
    at resolveModuleNamesWorker (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_mo
dules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:69728:158)
    at resolveModuleNamesReusingOldState (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogm
a\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:69872:24)
    at processImportedModules (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_modu
les\typescript\lib\typescript.js:70920:35)
    at findSourceFile (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_modules\type
script\lib\typescript.js:70830:17)
    at args (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_modules\typescript\lib
\typescript.js:70719:85)
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma
\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:70692:34)
    at processSourceFile (C:\Users\Niahc\Documents\web apps\Dogma\node_modules\t
ypescript\lib\typescript.js:70719:13)
GET /api/things 200 63.369 ms - -
```

Comment: Those files aren't processed by Typescript but this file is. If it is TS file, give it .ts extension. Don't try to do something the hard way, especially if you're new to this.

Comment: still get the error changing the name to either env.ts extension and env.js. Is there no way to remove this validation configuration?

Comment: I'm not sure what's this configuration is. It entirely depends on your project. And I'm not sure how env.ts cause same error. As opposed to .env, it's not unknown extension.